# How to limit the CPU load when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to load csv files into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, load

I'm using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in a php script so users can load csv files into MySQL (all data has been pre-escaped), which is good and fast, but when a script is doing that, it's spiking my CPU load to 100% while the process is happening - sometimes up to 2-3 minutes.

The csv files are a max of 5000 rows.

I think part of the problem is that the table is large now 30 million + rows, so re-indexing is compounding the problem.

Is there a way via php script to tell MySQL to limit the load?

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

On a Linux based server you can use PHP's [proc_nice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-nice.php) function to reduce the priority although there are a few limitations:

```
proc_nice(10);
```

Depending on the environment you are running the script in you may need to set the priority back to normal at the end of the script using `proc_nice(0);` to avoid PHP being stuck on a low priority.

An easier & less-troublesome way may be to simply add a [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) command to at the end of every loop so the processor has a chance to execute other tasks:

```
sleep(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try importing the only data structure first and then try importing the data that would avoid delay or connection loss at some time.

Try importing the data in chunks and not all at a time. This could help you in importing the data efficiently and quickly.

Comment: Thanks Marklong. I see what you mean, but even chunking it down to a couple thousand rows at a time results in a large wait (2-3 minutes) while MySQL is re-indexing before the next csv file can be uploaded. Also, the CPU load spikes to 100% during this reindexing.